# CALayer renderInContext draws a blank image

Tags: ios

This code works:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aRect.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:aRect afterScreenUpdates:YES];
anImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but I need to support iOS 5 and 6. My Googling says this code ought to work:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aRect.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
anImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but the image is blank. How do I take a snapshot of a view in iOS 5 and 6?

Comment: The code looks right - is QuartzCore framework linked in and included (e.g., `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to scale the view to fit it the bounds of the graphics context. Most examples I found of this assume that the source view and the destination context are the same size. The graphics context I was using was much smaller than the view being snapshotted, and it was actually just clipping a corner of the view that was transparent.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aRect.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat scale = CGRectGetWidth(aRect) / CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale, scale);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
anImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```